# Parsing works but data are not stored in nsMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsxmlparser

I am parsing an xml file , it works and show me the data parsed in the console( for example : processing value for Speller ...), but they aren't added to the msmutablearray users. Here is some code. Where is the problem ? help please :

```
- (MyData *) initXMLParser {
    [super init];
    // init array of user objects 
    users = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return self;
}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict 
{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"user"]) {
        NSLog(@"user element found – create a new instance of User class...");
        user = [[User alloc] init];

    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    if (!currentElementValue) {
        // init the ad hoc string with the value     
        currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    } else {
        // append value to the ad hoc string    
        [currentElementValue appendString:string];
    }
    NSLog(@"Processing value for : %@", string);
}  

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
 didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"users"]) {
        // We reached the end of the XML document
        return;
    }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"user"]) {

        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"userName"]) {
                [[self user] setUserName:currentElementValue];

            }
            if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"firstName"]) {
                [[self user] setFirstName:currentElementValue];

            }

            if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"lastName"]) {
                [[self user] setLastName:currentElementValue];

            }

        [users addObject:user];
        /*comboarray = [[users arrayForKey:@"ComboBoxValues"]
                      sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];*/

        // release user object
        [user release];
        user = nil;

    } else {

        [user setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];
           }

    [currentElementValue release];
    currentElementValue = nil;
}
-(BOOL)parseDocumentWithData:(NSData *)data {
    //NSString * filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Users" ofType:@"xml"];
    //data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    if (data == nil)
        return NO;

    // this is the parsing machine
    NSXMLParser *xmlparser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];

    // this class will handle the events
    [xmlparser setDelegate:self];
    [xmlparser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];

    // now parse the document
    BOOL ok = [xmlparser parse];
    if (ok == NO)
        NSLog(@"error");
    else
        NSLog(@"OK");

    [xmlparser release];
    return ok;
}


- (void) dealloc {

    [currentElementValue release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the problematic part of your code

```
- (MyData *) initXMLParser {
    [super init]; // change to self = [super init];
    // init array of user objects 
    users = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return self;
}
```

You are not initializing `self` with the value of `[super init];`

And add `[users release];` line to your `dealloc` call unless you release it elsewhere

Comment: I did it but it still not storing data :(

Comment: NSLog your users array throughout the calls of the parser, see if it is released somewhere, you're definitely doing something wrong with the memory management here

Comment: Yes it is a problem of memory management , i fixed it , i called the n-initxml . thanks it works :)

Answer (score 0):

change your didEndElement method with this:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
 didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"users"]) {
            // We reached the end of the XML document
             return;
        }
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"userName"]) {
            [[self user] setUserName:currentElementValue];
            [currentElementValue release];
            currentElementValue = nil;
        }
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"firstName"]) {
            [[self user] setFirstName:currentElementValue];
            [currentElementValue release];
            currentElementValue = nil;
        }

        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"lastName"]) {
            [[self user] setLastName:currentElementValue];
            [currentElementValue release];
            currentElementValue = nil;
        }

        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"user"]) {
           [users addObject:user];
           /*comboarray = [[users arrayForKey:@"ComboBoxValues"]
                  sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];*/

           // release user object
           [user release];
           user = nil;
       }
  }
```